# RegEx match on any of multiple groups

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to match on multiple regex groups

```
(^[0-9]) (^[$][0-9]) (^[$]{2}[0-9])
```

It would match the string if the first character is number, or if the first character is a `$` followed by a number, or if the first two characters are a `$` followed by a number.

Example strings that would match:

```
15271%
$3C001%
$$8244150928223C001%
```

Can this be done in one go, or would I have to check each match individually?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make make use of the pipe symbole | to achieve that. It basically behaves like an "or" in your regex pattern.

For example:

```
(banana|apple)
```

would match both "banana" and "apple".

In your case, you can also use a pattern like this

```
(\${0,2}\d.+)
```

to match all options: without $, with one $ and with two $.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
^\d.*|^\$\d.*|^\$\$\d.*
```

```
try {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"\A(?:^\d.*|^\$\d.*|^\$\$\d.*)\z", RegexOptions.Multiline)) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```